# Finding a sequence of step functions which converges uniformly to $x^c$ on $[1,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, step-function

The question is as follows,

> Given $b>1$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$, find a sequence of step functions $f_n$ which converges uniformly to $f(x) = x^c$ on $[1, b]$. Use the partition $1 = b^{0/n} < b^{1/n} < \cdots < b^{n/n} = b$.

I have chosen my sequence $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ as
$$
f_n(x) =
\begin{cases}
\left(b^{k/n}\right)^c &: x \in [b^{k/n}, b^{(k+1)/n}) ~~ \text{(for $k = 0, \ldots, n-1$)} \\
b^c &: x = b \\
\end{cases}
$$

Then I need to show $$(\forall \epsilon>0)(\exists N \in \mathbb{N})(\forall n \geq N)(\forall x \in [1, b]): |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$$

In the case $x=b$ we simply have
$$
|f_n(x)-f(x)|=|b^c-b^c|=0<\epsilon
$$

But in the case $x \in [b^{k/n}, b^{(k+1)/n})$ we have
$$
|f_n(x) - f(x)| = |b^{ck/n} - x^c| \leq |b^{ck/n}-b^{c(k+1)/n}|
$$

Then how would I choose the lower bound on $n$ such that this is always less then $\epsilon$?

Comment: Note that $$|b^{ck/n}-b^{c(k+1)/n}|=b^{ck/n}|1-b^{c/n}|\le \max\{1,b^c\}|1-b^{c/n}|.$$Noew, since $\max\{1,b^c\}$ is constant, bounding $|1-b^{c/n}|$ is quite easy.

Comment: This works, thank you very much.